# How to output JSON with PyExifTool

Tags: python, json, exiftool

I am running the following code to output a list of image and video files on a shared drive along with the creation date. However, I just cannot seem to get the `execute_json` method working properly. The [documentation](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/#exiftool.ExifTool.execute) for the project is not extensive.

```
def main():
    dir_name = '/Volumes/photo/phone backup/'
    tags = ["File Name", "CreateDate"]
    log_file = '/Volumes/photo/py_log.txt'

    file_names = getListOfFiles(dir_name)
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as e:
        metadata = e.execute_json(str(e.get_tags_batch(tags, file_names)))
    f = open(log_file, "w")
    f.write(metadata)
    f.close()
```

The error I receive is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`. If I alter the code a bit to this,

```
    file_names = getListOfFiles(dir_name)
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as e:
        metadata = e.get_tags_batch(tags, file_names)
    f = open(log_file, "w")
    f.write(str(metadata))
    f.close()
```

The resulting file has this format,

```
[{'SourceFile': '/Volumes/photo/phone backup/2017-05/MOV_0112.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:04:30 13:56:18'}, {'SourceFile': '/Volumes/photo/phone backup/2017-05/MOV_0174.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:06:09 06:12:47'}, {'SourceFile': '/Volumes/photo/phone backup/2017-05/MOV_0141.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:05:14 16:36:10'}
```

When I try and serialise this file, I get the error that this is not valid JSON.

Would appreciate some assistance as I am utterly lost.

I could replace the ' with " myself, but that seems an extremely ham-fisted solution.

**EDIT** After playing around with it a bit more - I do a `json.dump` call on the output `metadata`. After that calling it with `json.load` is not a problem. But doing the following,

```
for key in file_data:
    print (key)
```

results in this output,

```
{'SourceFile': '/Volumes/photo/phone backup/2017-05/MOV_0112.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:04:30 13:56:18'}
{'SourceFile': '/Volumes/photo/phone backup/2017-05/MOV_0174.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:06:09 06:12:47'}
```

So this is not a properly formatted JSON output at all that ExifTool is spitting. It's just basically a large text dump.

Comment: You're never serializing the data to JSON. You would need to use the `json` module to do that (via `json.dump` or `json.dumps`).

Comment: @larsks, see my latest edit above. I managed to iterate through the JSON finally, but it just looks like a large text dump.

Comment: Also, the [documentation](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/#exiftool.ExifTool.execute_json) states that this should return JSON, but it clearly doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the documentation. If we look at the docs for the `execute_json` method, it says:

> Execute the given batch of parameters and parse the JSON output.
>
> This method is similar to :py:meth:`execute()`.  It automatically adds the parameter `-j` to request JSON output from `exiftool` and parses the output.  The return value is a list of dictionaries, mapping tag names to the corresponding values.

This clearly states that the `exiftool` module **parses the output**, which is to say it reads the JSON data and returns a list of Python data structures.

Similarly, the documentation for `get_tags_batch` says:

> The format of the return value is the same as for :py:meth:`execute_json()`.

So when you do this...

```
    file_names = getListOfFiles(dir_name)
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as e:
        metadata = e.get_tags_batch(tags, file_names)
    f = open(log_file, "w")
    f.write(str(metadata))
    f.close()
```

...you're just writing the string representation of that data to a file (i.e., the output of `str(metadata)`). If you wanted to actually write JSON data, you would need to `import json` and then:

```
with open(log_file, 'w') as fd:
  json.dump(metadata, log_file)
```

To read in this file, we would use `json.load`:

```
with open(log_file, 'r') as fd:
  metadata = json.load(fd)
```

This gets us the original list of dictionaries.  For example, we could iterate over it like this:

```
for imageinfo in metadata:
  print('CreateDate:', imageinfo.get('EXIF:CreateDate', 'unknown'))
```

Here's the complete sample code I used to test this:

```
import exiftool
import json
import os


file_names = [f'images/{fn}' for fn in os.listdir('images')]
tags = ["File Name", "CreateDate"]
with exiftool.ExifTool() as e:
    metadata = e.get_tags_batch(tags, file_names)

with open('md.json', 'w') as fd:
    json.dump(metadata, fd)


with open('md.json', 'r') as fd:
    metadata = json.load(fd)


for imageinfo in metadata:
    print('Created: {}'.format(
        imageinfo.get('EXIF:CreateDate', 'unknown')
    ))
```

Running this against my local `images` directory, which contains 7 random images, results in:

```
Created: 2020:01:26 15:06:12
Created: 2020:04:16 18:13:48
Created: unknown
Created: unknown
Created: 2020:01:26 15:05:54
Created: 2020:04:16 18:07:41
Created: 2020:01:26 15:07:58
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Your example very clearly illustrated where I was going wrong, and I appreciate the help.